# Scale and keep ratio after rotating bitmap by using matrix

Tags: android, matrix, rotation, scale

I got a picture of a sun, 860x860 pixels.
I want to rotate the sun with the anchor-point being center of the screen.
This is what I got so far:

```
class GraphicalMenu extends View{

    int screenH;
    int screenW;
    int angle;
    Bitmap sun, monster;

    public GraphicalMenu(Context context){
        super(context);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;
        sun = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.sun,options);
        monster = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.monster,options);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        screenH = h;
        screenW = w;
        sun = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sun, w, h, true);
        monster = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(monster, w, h, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

      //Increase rotating angle.
        if (angle++ >360)
            angle =0;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setRotate(angle , getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
        canvas.drawBitmap(sun, matrix, new Paint());

        //Call the next frame.
        canvas.drawBitmap(monster,0 , 0, null);

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

I've tried to change this line:

```
sun = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sun, w, h, true);
```

to:

```
sun = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sun, h, h, true);
```

but then the sun leaves the center of the screen and rotates far out to the right. 
How can I fit the sun to the screen?
And how can I make it keep its ratio?

*edit*
Screenshot from running it on my N5 and the picture of the sun.
[image: screenshot]

[image: sun]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have several problems with your code:

1. If you're making multiple calls to onSizeChanged() then you'll want to keep the original bitmap (pre-scaled) otherwise when you upscale the bitmaps again, they will look pixelated because every time you downscale them, you're losing information.
2. When you provide a matrix through which to transform your bitmap for drawing onto the canvas, that matrix will apply to the bitmap itself, not the screen as a whole. So when you make the drawBitmap() call, what you are actually requesting is for the bitmap to be rotated around the local point (getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2), not the screen point.
3. You're not actually rotating around the screen centre, you're rotating around the View's centre. Unless the View takes up the entire screen, you won't get the intended effect.

I can't pinpoint exactly what your problem is, but uploading some images would likely clarify what you're trying to achieve and what your current situation is.

Comment: I set the canvas with: 
  GraphicalMenu gm = new GraphicalMenu(this);
  setContentView(gm); So it covers the whole screen. So width and height should be right. I also updated with pictures to hopefully make it easier to understand what I want to achieve. :)